# What is the correct name of a job involving mainly programming measurement instruments and making measurements on electronic components?

Tags: measurement

While revisioning my resume I found out that I do not know what is the industry standard name of one of my previous job. I simply called it "Software developer" but I don't think it fits properly.

The job involved the following:

1. Programming instruments (such as Keithley's voltage/current sources for example) to perform a certain sweep/measurement according to required specs.
2. Testing and implementing features on programs developed at point 1.
3. Perform measurements on electronic components and compare with datasheet specs.

I don't think "Laboratory technician" is a good fit either.

Comment: When you say "programming"  what does that mean exactly?  Are you adjusting the settings on the instrument, or are you writing software that will interface and setup the instrument?  If it was an engineering position "Test and Validation Engineer" is a recognized industry title.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about career classifications while this website is only for specific issues in the actual practice of Engineering.  Career questions are off topic.

Comment: @Clipboard_Waving_Enginerd writing software which was mostly SCPI, LabVIEW or a combination of both.

Comment: @ChrisStratton could you please suggest me where would be an appropriate place to move this question to?

Comment: @mickkk Sounds like a "Test Engineer" position to me,  "Test and Validation Engineer" is a title I held where my work was very similar.  Good luck on your job search!

Comment: @mickkk stack exchange does not offer a home for every possible question, in fact the design intent of these sites is quite purposefully narrow.  That there may not be a suitable place has no bearing on the fact that it does not belong *here*.  There is after all an entire rest of the Internet.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I understand. I often ask a suggestion anyway, since sometimes I get a useful pointer to the suitable place.

Comment: If the job is very specifically about the programming part, it might be called "test automation engineer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like the job of a [test engineer.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_engineer)